# Terminal "LoadModule" - command not found

Tags: terminal, homebrew, php

I installed via homebrew the new php56 version.

To activate it and use it I typed this in the Terminal:

```
LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

But it says: `-bash: LoadModule: command not found`

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadModule is for your Apache configuration file httpd.conf, not for being run in your shell.

Comment: thanks. But when I add this line to the file and run `php -v` it still says PHP 5.4 (but I installed 5.6)

Comment: @Akeno That's a completely separate issue—setting the version of PHP for your shell is different to setting it for Apache. Feel free to ask a separate question, preferably with a link to the tutorial you are following if appropriate.